# How to make media query only for portrait 1080p monitors, but not portrait 1080p phones?

Tags: css, media-queries

For the website I'm making, the mobile devices and portrait monitors seem to share the same media queries. How can I separate the two? The handheld query would have been perfect for this.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at media query orientation attribute? Do TVs report orientation? I would guess that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @SergChernata The orientation query only triggers when the width > height or vise-versa. It's not very smart. So it won't work for this problem. TV query is depreciated too.

Comment: What about DPI or pixel density?